# Async lambda expressions cannot be converted to expression trees

Tags: c#, linq, automapper

```
public static async Task<Bureau> getBubreauById(int? idBureau)
{
   if (idBureau > 0)
   {
      using (var dbContext = new AppDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
      {
           return await dbContext.Bureaus.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.id == idBureau);
       }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And in the **MapperInitializer**

```
.ForMember(aud => aud.LibelleBureauEnlevement, o => o.MapFrom(async au => (await SmartTransitHelper.getBubreauById(au.bureau_dedouanement)).libelle)
```

Here I wanna Map the **LibelleBureauEnlevement** to the returned libelle value from **SmartTransitHelper.getBubreauById(au.bureau_dedouanement)**
but I have this error, I wanna know what is wrog, why it's not workin?

Comment: automapper isn't designed to pull in things from other sources

Comment: When I make the function not awaitable evrything works fine

Comment: `await` is not part of expression trees.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/158